# Extracting lines between two patterns and including line above the first and below the second

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

Having the following text file, I need to extract and print strings between two patterns and ,also, include the line above the first pattern and the one following the second

```
asdgs sdagasdg sdagdsag
asdfgsdagg gsfagsaf 
asdfsdaf dsafsdfdsfas
asdfdasfadf
nnnn nnnnn aaaaa
line before first pattern
***** FIRST *****
dddd ffff cccc
wwww rrrrrrrr xxxx
***** SECOND *****
line after second pattern
asdfgsdagg gsfagsaf 
asdfsdaf dsafsdfdsfas
asdfdasfadf
nnnn nnnnn aaaaa
```

I have found many solution with sed and awk to extract between two tags as the following

```
sed -n '/FIRST/,/SECOND/p' FileName
```

but how to include the line before and after the pattern?

Desired output:

```
line before first pattern
***** FIRST *****
dddd ffff cccc
wwww rrrrrrrr xxxx
***** SECOND *****
line after second pattern
```

Comment: This is trivial in `ed`, since `ed`'s addressing is more evolved than `sed`: `printf '%s\n' "/FIRST/-;/SECOND/+p" q | ed -s FileName`. If you want to save that portion: `printf '%s\n' "/FIRST/-;/SECOND/+w NewFileName" q | ed -s FileName`.

Comment: Never use range expressions (`/FIRST/,/SECOND/`) as they make trivial things very slightly briefer but then require a complete rewrite and/or duplicate conditions when the problem becomes even the slightest bit more interesting, as you are now discovering. Always use a "found" flag instead, `'/FIRST/{f=1} f; /SECOND/{f=0}` (oh, and use awk, btw, not sed for this and anything else involving multiple lines).

Answer (score 3):

As you've asked for an `sed`/`awk` solution (and everyone is scared of `ed` ;-), here's one way you can do it in awk:

```
awk '/FIRST/{print p; f=1} {p=$0} /SECOND/{c=1} f; c--==0{f=0}' file
```

When the first pattern is matched, print the previous line `p` and set the print flag `f`. When the second pattern is matched set `c` to 1. If `f` is 1 (true), the current line will be printed. `c--==0` is only true the line after the second pattern is matched.

Another way you can do this is by looping through the file twice:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if(/FIRST/)s=NR;else if(/SECOND/)e=NR;next}FNR>=s-1&&FNR<=e+1' file file
```

The first pass through the file loops through the file and records the line numbers. The second prints the lines in the range.

The advantage of the second approach is that it is trivially easy to print M lines before and N lines after the range, simply by changing the numbers in the script.

To use shell variables instead of hard-coded patterns, you can pass the variables like this:

```
awk -v first="$first" -v second="$second" '...' file
```

Then use `$0 ~ first` instead of `/FIRST/`.

Comment: `c--==0` will keep decrementing c long after it's zero. You sure it won't wrap around if the file is huge? I always write `c&&c--` so c will stop decrementing when it hits zero.

Comment: It'll also behave undesirably if SECOND appears without/before a FIRST and it wont handle multiple ranges in the same file (or multiple files).

Comment: @Ed thanks for your comments, although I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting `c--==0` be changed to as `c&&c--` doesn't work in the same way. I would change my answer to make it more resilient but then it would basically be a copy of yours!

Comment: One option would be `/SECOND/{f=0;c=2} f||(c&&c--)` but it's not particularly intuitively obvious what that's doing! Alternatively `c&&c--; f{print; if(/SECOND/){c=1;f=0}}` or ....

Comment: @TomFenech : what if the FIRST and SECOND pattern were shell variables. I'm trying to use the -v switch bu no luck:  awk  -v  firstpattern=$FIRST -v secondpattern=$SECOND '/firstpattern/{print p; f=1} {p=$0} /secondpattern/{c=1} f; c--==0{f=0}' file

Comment: @Tom Fenech can you see below code , i used ur pattern and i am getting error when using variablename, last answer in this post . thank you.

Comment: @John same thing i am also doing with shell variable then it is not working .Did you got any alternate to do or any other solution?  kindly let me know.thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'd say

```
sed '/FIRST/ { x; G; :a n; /SECOND/! ba; n; q; }; h; d' filename
```

That is:

```
/FIRST/ {        # If a line matches FIRST
  x              # swap hold buffer and pattern space,
  G              # append hold buffer to pattern space.
                 # We saved the last line before the match in the hold
                 # buffer, so the pattern space now contains the previous
                 # and the matching line.
  :a             # jump label for looping
  n              # print pattern space, fetch next line.
  /SECOND/! ba   # unless it matches SECOND, go back to :a
  n              # fetch one more line after the match
  q              # quit (printing that last line in the process)
}
h                # If we get here, it's before the block. Hold the current
                 # line for later use.
d                # don't print anything.
```

Note that BSD sed (as comes with Mac OS X and *BSD) is a bit picky about branching commands. If you're working on one of those platforms,

```
sed -e '/FIRST/ { x; G; :a' -e 'n; /SECOND/! ba' -e 'n; q; }; h; d' filename
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

This will work whether or not there's multiple ranges in your file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/FIRST/ { print prev; gotBeg=1 }
gotBeg {
    print
    if (gotEnd)   gotBeg=gotEnd=0
    if (/SECOND/) gotEnd=1
}
{ prev=$0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
line before first pattern
***** FIRST *****
dddd ffff cccc
wwww rrrrrrrr xxxx
***** SECOND *****
line after second pattern
```

If you ever need to print more than 1 line before FIRST change `prev` to an array. If you ever need to print more than 1 line after SECOND, change `gotEnd` to a count.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '#n
   H;$!d
   x;s/\n/²/g
   /FIRST.*SECOND/!b
   s/.*²\([^²]*²[^²]*FIRST\)/\1/
:a
   s/\(FIRST.*SECOND[^²]*²[^²]*\)².\{1,\}/\1/
   ta
   s/²/\
/g
   p' YourFile
```

- POSIX sed version (GNU sed use `--posix`)
- take the following SECOND pattern also if on the same line, easy to adapt for taking at least one new line between

  - `#n` : don't print unless expres request (like `p`)
  - `H;$!d` : append each line to buffer, if not last line, delete current line and loop
  - `x;s/\n/²/g` : load buffer and replace any new line with another character (here i use `²`) because posix sed does not allow a `[^\n]`
  - `/FIRST.*SECOND/!b` : if no pattern presence, *quit* without output
  - `s/.*²\([^²]*²[^²]*FIRST\)/\1/` : remove everything before line before your first pattern
  - `:a` : label for a goto (used later)
  - `s/\(FIRST.*SECOND[^²]*²[^²]*\)².\{1,\}/\1/` : remove everything after a line after your second pattern. It take the biggest string so last occurence of the pattern is the reference
  - `ta` : if last `s///` occur, got to label `a`. It cyle, until first SECOND pattern occuring in file (after FIRST)
  - `s/²/\
    /g` : put back the new lines
  - `p` : print the result

Answer (score 0):

based on the Tom's comment: if the file isn't large we can just store it in the array, and then loop over it:

```
awk '{a[++i]=$0} /FIRST/{s=NR} /SECOND/{e=NR} END {for(i=s-1;i<e+1;i++) print a[i]}'
```

Comment: You don;t need to store the whole file, just the segment you're interested in and that would fail if there's multiple FIRST/SECOND segments or a SECOND without a FIRST or...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with Perl personally. We have the 'range operator' which we can use to detect if we're between two patterns:

```
if ( m/FIRST/ .. /SECOND/ )
```

That's the easy part. What's a little less easy is 'catching' the preceeding and next lines. So I set a `$prev_line` value, so that when I first hit that test, I know what to print. And I clear that `$prev_line`, both because then it's empty when I print it again, but also because then I can spot the transition at the end of the range.

So something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $prev_line = " ";
while (<DATA>) {
    if ( m/FIRST/ .. /SECOND/ ) {
        print $prev_line;
        $prev_line = '';
        print;
    }
    else {
        if ( not $prev_line ) {
            print;
        }
        $prev_line = $_;
    }
}

__DATA__ 
asdgs sdagasdg sdagdsag
asdfgsdagg gsfagsaf 
asdfsdaf dsafsdfdsfas
asdfdasfadf
nnnn nnnnn aaaaa
line before first pattern
***** FIRST *****
dddd ffff cccc
wwww rrrrrrrr xxxx
***** SECOND *****
line after second pattern
asdfgsdagg gsfagsaf 
asdfsdaf dsafsdfdsfas
asdfdasfadf
nnnn nnnnn aaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/FIRST/!{h;d};H;g;:a;n;/SECOND/{n;q};$!ba' file
```

If the current line is not `FIRST` save it in the hold space and delete the current line. If the line is `FIRST` append it to the saved line and then print both and any further lines untill `SECOND` when an additional line is printed and the script exited.